# How to remove duplicate value in IntegerArray in android app development

Tags: android, android-intent

I would like to know how to remove duplicate values in Integer Array.

I think you may face This question in all languages.

But in android I don't know how to achieve this.Can anyone please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Even without Java tricks, it is a basic algorithm...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure your array is `Integer` type not `int`

```
Integer[] array; // Your integer array...

Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
Collections.addAll(set, array);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    val finalArrayList: ArrayList<String>
    val arrayList = arrayListOf<String>()

    arrayList.add("ABC")
    arrayList.add("XYZ")
    arrayList.add("ABZ")
    arrayList.add("ABC")
    arrayList.add("XYZ")
    arrayList.add("ABZ")

    finalArrayList = arrayList.toSet().toList() as ArrayList<String>


    Answer
    arrayList: [ABC, XYZ, ABZ, ABC, XYZ, ABZ]
    finalArrayList: [ABC, XYZ, ABZ]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this Code**

```
public static void removeDuplicateWithOrder(ArrayList arlList)
{
   Set set = new HashSet();
   List newList = new ArrayList();
   for (Iterator iter = arlList.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
      Object element = iter.next();
      if (set.add(element))
         newList.add(element);
   }
   arlList.clear();
   arlList.addAll(newList);
}
```